# Get values from Table A even if it does not exists in Table B based on Table B criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

This might sound really easy and dumb for the champs of SQL language. I need some help.

I have two tables

**Table A - Product**

| ProductCode | ProductName |
| --- | --- |
| APPLMAC | Apple Mac |
| APPLIPH | Apple iPhone |
| APPLWTC | Apple Watch |

**Table B - Sales**

| OrderID | ProductCode | Sales | OrderDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | APPLMAC | $1300 | 2021-08-11 |
| 2 | APPLMAC | $1300 | 2021-08-12 |
| 3 | APPLMAC | $1300 | 2021-08-12 |
| 4 | APPLMAC | $1300 | 2021-08-13 |
| 5 | APPLIPH | $999 | 2021-08-11 |

I want to write a query that would give me the following result and rank them highest to lowest and show 0 if there were no sales.

| ProductName | TotalSales |
| --- | --- |
| Apple Mac | $5200 |
| Apple iPhone | $999 |
| Apple Watch | $0 |

**My current query only gives me**

| ProductName | TotalSales |
| --- | --- |
| Apple Mac | $5200 |
| Apple iPhone | $999 |

The query I have written is as follows

```
SELECT SR.Description,COALESCE(sum(OH.TotalSellPrice), 0)
FROM Enterprise32.dbo.Product as SR
RIGHT JOIN Enterprise32.dbo.Salesas OH on OH.SalesRepCode = SR.Code
where OrderDate BETWEEN DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()-1)/7, 0)  AND DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()-1)/7, 5) 
GROUP BY SR.Description
```

Answer (score 1):

User a `LEFT JOIN` starting with the table where you want to keep everything.

Move the conditions on all but the first table to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT SR.Description, COALESCE(sum(OH.TotalSellPrice), 0)
FROM Enterprise32.dbo.Product SR LEFT JOIN
     Enterprise32.dbo.Salesas OH 
     ON OH.SalesRepCode = SR.Code AND
        OrderDate BETWEEN DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()-1)/7, 0) AND
                           DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()-1)/7, 5) 
GROUP BY SR.Description
```